# Batch create based on user selection in Odoo

Tags: batch-processing, odoo

I have the following models Program, Course, ProgramAdmission, CourseEnrollment.
Each course is associated with a program.

During program admission, I am showing the list of available courses for the selected program. For each shown course, I want to show a dropdown menu with the following selections: Not Planned and Planned.

Now if the user saves the new program admission, I want also to enroll the user in the planned courses by creating CourseEnrollment in the server-side for each planned course.

And if the user discards the new program admission, nothing should be created in the database.

How can I allow for such conditional batch creation of model objects?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you just need to start to coding it. Create the module with the models relations and fields. On the `ProgramAdmission` model add a Many2one field to the `Program` model and another to the `Course` model. If you cancel the form while creating a new record nothing will be saved in your DB, but if you hit the Save button it will call the `create` method for new records and `write` methods for existing ones. Override the create method to be able to dynamically create a new record of the `CourseEnrollment` model and associate it with the `ProgramAdmission` record to be created by saving it to a new Many2one field in the same `ProgramAdmission` model.

To make what I mean more clear:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class Program(models.Model):
    _name = 'school.program'

    name = fields.Char()


class Course(models.Model):
    _name = 'school.course'

    name = fields.Char()


class ProgramAdmission(models.Model):
    _name = 'school.program.admission'

    course_id = fields.Many2one('school.course')
    program_id = fields.Many2one('school.program')
    enrollment_id = fields.Many2one('school.course.enrollment')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        enrollment_id = self.env['school.course.enrollment'].create({
            'course_id': vals['course_id'],
            'program_id': vals['program_id']
        })
        vals['enrollment_id'] = enrollment_id.id
        return super(ProgramAdmission, self).create(vals)


class CourseEnrollment(models.Model):
    _name = 'school.course.enrollment'

    course_id = fields.Many2one('school.course')
    program_id = fields.Many2one('school.program')
```